# How to make an image be dragged around on top of another image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html file which positions one image on top of another. However I wish to that the superimposed image can be dragged around by the user, confined within the boundaries of the underlying image. Anyone may be kind enough to provide suggestions?

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">

  #about {
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:3%;
    opacity: 0.6;
  }

  #main-content-image {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
  }

  </style>


  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){    

    $(function () {
      var img = new Image();
      $(img).load(function () {
        $('#main-content-image').append(this);
      }).attr('src', 'foo.jpg');
    });

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="main-content-image">
    <img id="about" src='bar.jpg'>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to drag and drop or just move the image on top of another image?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're still using jQuery 1.3.2? It's over 6.5 years out of date.

Comment: I just want to move the superimposed image around.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No not at all. I will make a note to use the latest version.

Comment: @dave that is exactly what I wanted. Would you like to answer the question?

Comment: Click the "view source" link on the page he pointed you at - that shows you how to do it.

Comment: @SouvikDas sure, I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31167479/361762)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [jQueryUI Draggable Widget](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement) which allows you define a [containment setting](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment), which will not allow moving outside of the bounding box.

Here's a small example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable3").draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false });
});
```

```css
.draggable { width: 90px; height: 90px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; }
#containment-wrapper { width: 95%; height:150px; border:2px solid #ccc; padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="containment-wrapper">
  <div id="draggable3" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p>I'm contained within the box</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the function draggable from jQuery UI.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        $("#draggable").draggable();
    });

});
```

Here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/rv8kcjqd/